# Empty point or asymptote

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, asymptotics

I've encountered the two functions: 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\ln x -1}$$
$$g(x) = \ln(8x-x^2)$$
I know that in $x=0$ both functions are undefined, but I can't really understand why in $ g(x)$ there is an asymptote in $ x = 0$ while in $f(x)$ there's an empty point in $x = 0$.
Will be happy to an explaination, thanks in advance :)

Comment: what exactly is an empty point for you?

Comment: @user190080 a point on the graph where the function is undefined but still has a $y$ value, like $(0,1)$. wheras a vertical asymptote which is a linear function like $$ x = c$$ when $c \in \Bbb R$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that as $x\to0^+$, we have

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac1{\ln(x)-1}=0$$

Since $\ln(x)$ gets infinitely big, so the fraction gets infinitely small.  Thus, that point is not an asymptote, but just an empty point.

It does, however, have asymptotes at $x=e$...

Comment: it must be $$x$$ tends to $$0^{+}$$ since we have $$x>0$$

Comment: :-P Thanks for the nit-pick @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: Ok, so let me see if I got it. for the function $$ y = \frac{ \ln^3 x +4}{\ln x -1}$$ there might be an asynptote in $ x = e$. But I have to affirm if by computing the limit $$ \lim_{x \to e} \frac{ \ln^3 x +4}{\ln x -1}$$ but it seems peculiar because the denominator is tending to 0 $$ \lim_{x \to e} \frac{ 3 \ln e +4}{\ln e -1}$$

Comment: @Ozk Yup.  You have to determine if it actually goes to $\pm\infty$ to be an asymptote.

Comment: @SimpleArt I've made another change while you wrote a comment, please review it.

Comment: @Ozk Huh?  If the denominator tend to $0$ and the numerator tend to a non-zero value, it should be an asymptote most likely.

Comment: @SimpleArt Why is it? can I assume from it that: $$a \in \Bbb R, a \ne 0 \implies \frac{a}{0} = \pm \infty$$

Comment: @Ozk Hm... see if you can prove it :D  Because it should be like that.

Comment: @SimpleArt Haha, I'm only in high school level (tho I want to start learning at a higher level) so till now in elementary and middle school we've been told that something devided by zero in undefined. Now even the teacher seems not sure about that.

Comment: @Ozk Well, then I guess I'll just say if there is an infinitely small number in the denominator, the fraction becomes infinitely big, provided the numerator does not cancel the "small-ness"

Comment: @SimpleArt guess it will be more correct to say that $$a \in \Bbb R, a \ne 0 \implies \frac{a}{0^{\pm}} = \pm \infty$$

Comment: when $0^{\pm} $ represents a small number from the positive direction and a bot nimber from the negative direction of the X axis, respectively.

Comment: @Ozk Haha... bot nimber... and I think that would be the right direction if you wanted to prove it :D